# How to fix function that it works for all cases?

Tags: python, string

This function should be to separate string by '-', but it works only for case when string has two same letter, so when string has more same letters - it doesn't work

```
def seperating(s: string): 
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[i + 1]:
            return s[:i + 1] + '-' + s[i + 1:]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(seperating("   aa   "))  # - - a-a - -     it doesn't work
    print(seperating("Hello"))  # Hel-lo   it works
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning from the function after the first time you encounter two equal characters.instead of returning a value, save it in a new string e.g:

```
def seperating(s: string):
    ret_string = ""
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        ret_string += s[i]
        if s[i] == s[i + 1]:
            ret_string += '-'
    ret_string += s[len(s) - 1]
    return ret_string
```

Comment: @Gsquare Right, Thanks